# Save as on change input file

Tags: jquery, vb.net, html

Good morning,

I have a file named UploadIMG.aspx with some code html and UploadIMG.aspx.vb and this one empty.

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h3>Click to add</h3>
</div>
```

And my jquery looks like this:

```
$("h3").click(function () {
$(".wrapper").append("\
   <img id='uploadPreview1' width='200' height='100' /> \
   <input id='MyFile' class='inputImage' type='file' onchange='UploadImage();'/>");
});
```

I made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bd4j9v4r/

I want to upload the image to my server whenever they change it on the input but without pressing any button.

I tried to save it with SaveAs but I don't know how to apply this to an onchange.

```
<script runat="server">
Sub UploadButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If (MyFile.HasFile) Then
        Dim fileName As String = MyFile.FileName
        MyFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/img/") & MyFile.FileName)
    Else
    End If
End Sub
</script>
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of this change:

```
$(document).on('change', '.inputImage', function(){
   console.log(this.value);
   // now here you can upload this file.
});
```

Like if you are interested in fileupload with ajax:

```
$(document).on('change', '.inputImage', function(){
   console.log(this.value);
   var formData = new FormData();
   $.ajax({
       url:'', // place your controller's method
       type:'post',
       dataType:'', // text, json etc
       contentType:false,
       processData:false,
       success:function(data){},
       error:function(err){}
   });
});
```

Comment: For better performance you can delegate the event to your wrapper element (which always exists) instead of document.

Comment: So if I want to use ajax do I have to put my upload function on the aspx.vb and call it giving the image as a dataType parameter?

Comment: @wintercounter agreed.

Comment: @JoaquimRedondo `dataType` is required if you are returning somthing from the server in types of like `html, text, json, script`.

Comment: @wintercoutner so... I have to send formData which will have the image? Excuse me I am a little lost on managing files.